# How to specify which key/value pairs to exclude in spaCy's Doc.to_disk(path, exclude=['user_data'])?

Tags: spacy, doc

My nlp pipeline has some doc extensions that store 3 items (a string for file name and two dicts which map non-serializable objects). I'd like only to exclude the non-serializable key/value pairs in the user data, but keep the filename.

```
doc.to_disk(path, exclude=['user_data'])
```

works as expected, excluding all user data. There are apparently options to instead exclude either 'user_data_keys' or 'user_data_values' but I find no explanation of their usage, and furthermore I can't think of any good reason to store either all the keys without the values or all the values without the keys!

I would like to exclude both keys and values of only certain fields in the doc.user_data. If this is possible, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify which keys or values you want to exclude.

https://spacy.io/api/doc#serialization-fields

```py
data = doc.to_bytes(exclude=["text", "tensor"])
doc.from_disk("./doc.bin", exclude=["user_data"])
```

Per this thread [here](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/issues/82), you can try the following work around:

```py
    def remove_unserializable_results(doc):
        doc.user_data = {}
        for x in dir(doc._):
            if x in ['get', 'set', 'has']: continue
            setattr(doc._, x, None)
        for token in doc:
            for x in dir(token._):
                if x in ['get', 'set', 'has']: continue
                setattr(token._, x, None)
        return doc

nlp.add_pipe(remove_unserializable_results, last=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already read the documentation extensively. My question is specific to excluding specific non-serializable custom extensions, which is not described in the documentation.

Comment: I added a potential work-around for unserialized results. Hope it helps.